# How to use stringr::str_match_all inside dplyr::mutate in the tidyverse pipe

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr, mutate

Using stringr::str_match, I can create a column that contains the characters after "H45" for the first instance of "H45" in each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble::tibble(A = c("H459 A452 H4544", "A452", "H4535"))

df <- df %>% mutate(H45_value = 
           str_match(A, 'H45([[0-9]]{1,2})') %>% 
           .[,2])
```

I would like to create a column using stringr::str_match_all that contains the characters after *every* appearance of "H45" in each row. However, I can't get str_match_all to run in the tidyverse pipe. I think it's because I don't know the correct syntax for calling [[1]][,2] within the pipe.

It works as an independent line of code:

`str_match_all("H459 A452 H4544", 'H45([[0-9]]{1,2})')[[1]][,2]`

I am hoping for output like this, where the first value of "H45_value" is a list or similar:

| A | H45_value |
| --- | --- |
| H459 A452 H4544 | 9, 44 |
| A452 | NA |
| H4535 | 35 |

Answer (score 1):

`str_extract_all()` is a better function choice as it returns a list of extracted values by default rather than the matrix returned by `str_match_all()`.  So you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(H45_value = str_extract_all(A, "(?<=H45)\\d+"))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  A               H45_value
  <chr>           <list>   
1 H459 A452 H4544 <chr [2]>
2 A452            <chr [0]>
3 H4535           <chr [1]>
```

Where `H45_value` contains:

```
[[1]]
[1] "9"  "44"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "35"
```

If you wanted to use `str_match_all()` you would need to iterate over the result and extract the second column:

```
df %>%
  mutate(H45_value = lapply(str_match_all(A, 'H45([[0-9]]{1,2})'), `[`, , 2))
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the lapply code to run by adding df$, but I can't get it to run in a pipe. Do you know how this could be done? Also, if it's possible to get the kind of output you got with str_extract_all?

Comment: You just need to place it inside mutate - have edited to show.